# Erro ao executar uma Trigger

Tags: oracle, trigger

Estou tendo o seguinte erro ao executar minha trigger, como poderia resolver?

**ERRO**

*Da erro quando dou insert na tabela compra_produto para calcular total
INSERT into compra_produto (CPR_CODIGO, PRO_CODIGO,CPP_QTDE, CPP_PRECO,CPP_DESCONTO)
    VALUES (1,2,7,87,0);
ORA-04091: a tabela ADMIN.COMPRA_PRODUTO é mutante; talvez o gatilho/função não possa localizá-la
ORA-06512: em "ADMIN.TRG_TOTAL_COMPRA_PRODUTO", line 3
ORA-04088: erro durante a execução do gatilho 'ADMIN.TRG_TOTAL_COMPRA_PRODUTO'*

**TRIGGER**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TRG_TOTAL_COMPRA_PRODUTO" 
    BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON COMPRA_PRODUTO

    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE  

BEGIN

    UPDATE COMPRA_PRODUTO SET CPP_TOTAL = 
        (
            SELECT ((CPP_TOTAL * CPP_QTDE) - (((CPP_TOTAL * CPP_QTDE) * CPP_DESCONTO) / 100)) FROM COMPRA_PRODUTO
                WHERE CPP_CODIGO = :NEW.CPP_CODIGO AND
                        PRO_CODIGO = :NEW.PRO_CODIGO
        ) 
    WHERE CPR_CODIGO = :NEW.CPR_CODIGO;

END;
```

**Insert**

```
INSERT INTO COMPRA_PRODUTO (CPR_CODIGO, PRO_CODIGO, CPP_QTDE, CPP_PRECO, CPP_DESCONTO) 
    VALUES (1,3,9,90, 0);
```

**Relação do Banco de Dados**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual a duvida??

Comment: Da erro quando dou insert na tabela compra_produto para calcular total
INSERT into compra_produto (CPR_CODIGO, PRO_CODIGO,CPP_QTDE, CPP_PRECO,CPP_DESCONTO)
    VALUES (1,2,7,87,0);

ORA-04091: a tabela ADMIN.COMPRA_PRODUTO é mutante; talvez o gatilho/função não possa localizá-la
ORA-06512: em "ADMIN.TRG_TOTAL_COMPRA_PRODUTO", line 3
ORA-04088: erro durante a execução do gatilho 'ADMIN.TRG_TOTAL_COMPRA_PRODUTO'

Comment: Parece que a tabela não está no mesmo schema. Crie um sinônimo público para a tabela COMPRA_PRODUTO e tente novamente. Oracle Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm

Comment: só existe apenas um esquema, eu ouvi falar sobre fazer select na mesma tabela da trigger, não posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Este é o famoso caso de [tabelas mutantes](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora04091.php), que basicamente são triggers que tentam consultar/modificar a mesma tabela que dispara a trigger, é um comportamento padrão do oracle.

Para solucionar o seu problema será necessário tratar este calculo diretamente na operação de insert/update ou criar um procedimento que é disparado após a realização destas operações.

Comment: Creio que o select seja desnecessário pois os valores da coluna estão emponteirados  pelo ":new" , < :new.CPP_TOTAL = :newCPP_TOTAL * ... > a própria coluna CPP_TOTAL poderia ser virtual calculada https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1